# Evaluating the First Character of a User Defined Variable is Uppercase

Tags: command-line, for-loop, cmd, uppercase

I have a template document that I want to convert to another file with a user defined name.  The following is the code I have pieced together.

```
rem @echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

cls

:Check_Filename
set "_Filename="
set /p _Filename=Enter filename to be created:

if not defined _Filename echo You must enter a value. Try again.&goto Check_Filename

set "test=%_Filename:~0,1%"

for %%C in (A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z) do if defined test set "test=!test:%%C=!"

if defined test echo Invalid input. Try again.&goto Check_Filename

if not defined test echo %_Filename%
Set "errorlevel="
echo %_Filename% | findstr /i /R ".java" > nul

if %errorlevel% == 0 (
echo Java extention located
type f:\java\Template.txt > f:\java\%_Filename%
echo %errorlevel% 

) else (
echo Java extention not located
echo %errorlevel%
type f:\java\Template.txt > f:\java\%_Filename%.java
)
)
```

It works but because the file is being used to create the backbone of Java script I want the FOR statement to evaluate the case of the first character which it does not presently do.  I tried using HEX representation of these characters in the FOR statement as well, but without success.

Could someone please help me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
@echo off & setlocal
:Check_Filename
set "_Filename="
set /p "_Filename=Enter filename to be created: "

if not defined _Filename echo You must enter a value. Try again.&goto:Check_Filename

echo(%_Filename:~0,1% | findstr /r "[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ]" || (echo Invalid input. Try again.&goto:Check_Filename)
```

Comment: Perfect.  Thank you so much.  I only wasted about 12 hours trying to fix the problem :).